# Number of possible binary strings of length k

Tags: puzzle

One of my friends was asked this question recently:

You have to count how many binary strings are possible of length "K".
Constraint: Every 0 has a 1 in its immediate left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question can be reworded:
How many binary sequences of length K are posible if there are no two consecutive 0s, but the first element should be 1 (else the constrains fails). Let us forget about the first element (we can do it bcause it is always fixed).
Then we got a very famous task that sounds like this: "What is the number of binary sequences of length K-1 that have no consecutive 0's." The explanation can be found, for example, [here](http://radio-weblogs.com/0122027/2003/08/20.html)

Then the answer will be F(K+1) where F(K) is the K`th fibonacci number starting from (1 1 2 ...).

Comment: How does this relate to Fibonacci, can you provide some intuition behind it?

Comment: @Chander Shivdasani: Edited an answer. If you do not undersand the referenced explanation I can do it here

Answer (score 0):

`∑ From n=0 to ⌊K/2⌋ of (K-n)Cn`; n is the number of zeros in the string

The idea is to group every 0 with a 1 and find the number of combinations of the string, for n zeros there will be n ones grouped to them so the string becomes (k-n) elements long. There can be no more than of <sup>K</sup>/<sub>2</sub> zeros as there would not have enough ones to be to the immediate left of each zero.
E.g. `111111[10][10]1[10]` for K = 13, n = 3